# Why is a URL in the middle of a function not causing an error?

Tags: javascript

By mistake, an URL was pasted into a JavaScript snippet. Reduced to a minimum, it looked roughly like this:

```
function(){
  /* a bunch of code */
  http://www.stackoverflow.com
  /* a bunch of code */
  return "it still works";
}
```

It was overlooked for quite some time, because it did not produce an error. Why is that? Why does this function still run without erroring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're defining a label called `http`. The `//` in the url comments the rest out.

see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 2):

Before returning a string value of **it still works** it is creating a label `http:` note the usage of `:`. And the remaining part of the code is commented out using the Single Line comment: `//`

There wasn't any sort of error in your code, because there was no Syntax error in your code. That's why it worked correctly.